# Maintaining consistency between downscaled representation and real world data?

Tags: jquery, html, css, graph, web

I have inherited a project written in jQuery that allows users to drag and drop items (draggable divs) onto a page (a bigger div). The page is draggable and resizable and items may be placed freely or snapped to each other and the edge of the page. Items cannot hang off the edge of the page or overlap.

The data to create these items is read in from another program. Each item has a "real" integer width and height with units of 1/10mm's. To create the divs representing these items these "real units" are converted to pixels using a scaling factor (currently 50%, we'd like to make it dynamic in the future so users can zoom in and out).

When the user is satisfied with the placement of items on the page they can then export their design. The x,y pixel placement of the items relative to the top left corner of the page is converted back to "real units" using the same scaling factor.

Items need to snap to a 5x5 real unit (0.5mm) grid. Obviously this is impossible because 5 real units = 2.5px, although we'd like this to work regardless of scale factor.

What is the easiest way to go back and forth between real units and pixels, making sure that  the real units are always on the grid, while keeping the pixel representation consistent? Can this be done while still leaning on the jQuery draggable/droppable/resizable classes or am I better off rewriting the whole thing?

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself when you say that items need to snap to a 5x5 grid but have previously stated that items may be placed freely. Also, how has the previous developer addressed the rounding issue with the 5x5 real unit grid? And how has he addressed the rounding issues with the real world items when they are represented in the browser? When the user resizes the page does it scale the canvas (and the items within it) or does it simply alter the dimensions?

Comment: As of right now, they can be placed freely and nothing snaps to grid. We'd like to implement the snap to grid. Dealing with that rounding error is why I'm here. Resizing the page doesn't scale the canvas, it just increases/decreases the amount of space around the outside of the canvas.

Comment: But presumably even before you've implemented your snapping to grid functionality you have a rounding issue on any of the real elements which are not even dimensions? How has the previous developer negotiated this issue? I wonder if Flash might be a more suitable choice of technology for this since it supports sub-pixel drawing.